# Django - Join 3 tables to get records

Tags: python, django

Need to join these 3 tables , can someone give me the ORM queryset . need to show the records on one template based on these three tables.

Models.py

```
class Item_Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    qty_in_ferma_warehouse = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    status = models.BooleanField()
    ListID = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True,blank=True)


class Order_Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    notes = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateField()
    status = EnumField(Choice,max_length=2, null=True,blank=True)
    Total_Amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    must_fill_in_items = models.IntegerField()
    total_replenish_small_order = models.IntegerField()
    order_type = EnumField(Choice3,max_length=2, null=True,blank=True)
    delivery_method = EnumField(Choice6, max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)



class Orderitems_Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order_Table,on_delete='')
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item_Table,on_delete='')
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    next_order_qty = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    Rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    status = EnumField(Choice2,max_length=2,null=True,blank=True)
    accumulated_residual_item = models.IntegerField()
    accumulated_damaged_item = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: One  more Question . i have a html form need to post the data into DB , can anyone help me to write the function for View.py

Comment: you can use django `ModelForm` to handle posting and saving. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: can you gave me some code . i have attached the image of the form ,it can have multiple items . till now i have not used forms.py in my project .

Comment: https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d you can follow this

Answer (score 0):

You can have a many to many field in `Order_Table`.

```py
items = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Orderitems_Table')
```

then you can query on `Order_Table` model and have a queryset

you can go through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) to have more insights about `ManyToMany` Field and how to play with this

For forms and view you can follow [this link](https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d)

Comment: Hi Shourav can i get ur mail ID . i m new in Django need to discuss few things.. thanks